# Does `BufferGeometry.attributes.color` in `three.js` support hexadecimal color?

Tags: three.js, drake

I'm using `meshcat_python` -- a visualization library built on top of `three.js` -- to visualize pointclouds. Color is currently sent as an `nx3` array of floats, but to save bandwidth I'd  prefer to send an array of `n` hexidecimal triplets. However, I haven't been able to get it to work.

I'm starting from code that looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import meshcat.geometry as g
from meshcat.servers.zmqserver import start_zmq_server_as_subprocess
from pydrake.all import ConnectMeshcatVisualizer, DiagramBuilder, AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph

# pydrake code -- not important to the question, but here as a MRE
server_proc, zmq_url, web_url = start_zmq_server_as_subprocess()
builder = DiagramBuilder()
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=1)
viz = ConnectMeshcatVisualizer(builder, scene_graph, zmq_url=zmq_url)

# point cloud visualization
n = 100
position = np.random.random((3, n))
color = np.random.random((3, n))
g_pc = g.PointCloud(position=position, color=color, size=0.1)

viz.vis.set_object(g_pc)

while True:
    pass
```

This sends `three.js` the result of `g_pc.lower()`, which in this case looks like:
`{'metadata': {'version': 4.5, 'type': 'Object'}, 'geometries': [{'uuid': '0c16e79b-f62b-11eb-ba95-05197ba30d28', 'type': 'BufferGeometry', 'data': {'attributes': {'position': {'itemSize': 3, 'type': 'Float32Array', 'array': <umsgpack.Ext object at 0x7f1dd63b5970>, 'normalized': False}, 'color': {'itemSize': 1, 'type': 'Float32Array', 'array': <umsgpack.Ext object at 0x7f1dd63b5940>, 'normalized': False}}}}], 'materials': [{'uuid': '0c16e79c-f62b-11eb-ba95-05197ba30d28', 'type': 'PointsMaterial', 'color': 16777215, 'size': 0.01, 'vertexColors': 2}], 'object': {'uuid': '0c16e79d-f62b-11eb-ba95-05197ba30d28', 'type': 'Points', 'geometry': '0c16e79b-f62b-11eb-ba95-05197ba30d28', 'material': '0c16e79c-f62b-11eb-ba95-05197ba30d28', 'matrix': [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}}` .

That's a lot of text, but as far as I can tell the relevant part is `'color': {'itemSize': 3, 'type': 'Float32Array', 'array': <umsgpack.Ext object at 0x7f1dd63b5940>, 'normalized': False}`; i.e., color is an `nx3` array as desired.

When I try:

```
...
color = np.ones(n) * 0x0000FF #blue
...
```

the result of `g_pc.lower()` is `'color': {'itemSize': 1, 'type': 'Float32Array', 'array': <umsgpack.Ext object at 0x7f1dd63b5940>, 'normalized': False}` -- an array of shape `n`, as desired.

However, the resulting visualization is all red. In fact, as far as I can tell an array of length `n` is always visualized as if it represented the floating point red component of a color: i.e., the red channel of the visualization is the array clipped to `[0, 1]` and the other channels are zero.

I'm not sure if this is because of `meshcat` or `three.js`, but I'd appreciate suggestions with regards to either: does a `three.js` `BufferGeometry` support hexadecimal color at all?

Answer (score 1):

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry

BufferGeometry is not inherently purposed for display. Often one would combine BufferGeometry with a Material to create a Mesh or Points... though the material may be LineMaterial or wireframe. Of course you don't have to follow through to a visible outcome. You don't have to add any geometry to a scene or use all variables you create. Perhaps its properties are referenced indirectly. The color attribute may be assigned incorrectly or as a surrogate for userData. Perhaps a modified THREE repo uses the Float32Array to properly pre-allocate system RAM for a MatLab shader, or some such blog tutorial?

Comment: I see -- so like in this example https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_custom_attributes_particles.html,
where `BufferGeometry` is just used to hold values for a `THREE.Points` object. But that doesn't totally answer the question -- that example also has the colors as an `nx3` array of floats, and I don't see any description in the documentation of either `BufferGeometry` or `Points` for what the allowable values of `color` are? I also haven't been able to find any examples online of `Points` or `BufferGeometry` being used with anything but float colors.

Comment: Did you mistake a THREE.Color for a shader's float32Array? Shader is more low-level, so Three documentation does not encompass that extensively. There is probably an allocation in the code which is not commented. Line 99+ of the example sets the Points color(s). InstancedMesh also pre-allocates a color pointer until initialized.